# Sendgrid working from terminal but not in pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, sendgrid

I am trying to connect a basic mail sender sendgrid function to my program's pipeline. Problem is when I do necessery commands from terminal it works fine like :

```sh
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env

echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore

source ./sendgrid.env

python3 sendgrid_mail.py
```

but when I try to run it from PyCharm it gives me HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized 
error.

```py
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

def mail_sender():
    message = Mail(
        from_email='from_mail',
        to_emails='to_mail',
        subject='hello pycharm',
        html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('my_api_key'))
        response = sg.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

mail_sender()
```

Comment: Did you set environment variables in PyCharm task configuration?

Comment: Yes that did solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how you're running in PyCharm. I'm guessing your environment variable is not actually set while you are in PyCharm. Try looking at the API key and see if it's what you're expecting (Either just print or use the debugger)

You can modify the environment variables in your run configuration

`Run | Edit Configurations... | Select the run configuration you're using | Environment variables ....`

You could also try setting the environment variable prior to starting PyCharm and it might pick it up, but that depends on a-lot of other things.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you! Still didnt understand why pycharm is not getting the env variables when i do necessarry command from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the environment variable `my_api_key`, but you're setting your environment variable as `SENDGRID_API_KEY` in the sendgrid.env. These two names need to match.

I'm assuming `YOUR_API_KEY` in your sendgrid.env file is the api key you've created. If not, that would need to be replaced with a real value.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for answer. I have already tried what you said in first parahraph before posting here but it didnt worked. I also write "real api code" that i have to "my_api_key" part and it didnt worked either.  I think my problem might be in the connection between enviroment and py file.